# I want to change audio source onClick

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to change audio source onClick button. I am trying this but I can't take a result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWVf4.png)

```js
data() {
    return {
      audioSrc: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setActiveAudio(item) {
      this.$refs.audioElm.src = item;
      this.$refs.audioElm.currentTime = 0;
      this.$refs.audioElm.crossOrigin = 'anonymus';
      this.$refs.audioElm.play();
    },
  },
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<span class="voice-btn" @click="setActiveAudio('../assets/voice.mp3')"> Click Sound</span>
<audio ref="audioElm" :src="audioSrc"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a timer to make sure the DOM has been updated before you interact with the element like

```
    data() {
    return {
      audioSrc: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setActiveAudio(item) {
      this.audioSrc = item;

      var element = this.$refs.audioElm;
      setTimeout(function()
      {
        element.currentTime = 0;
        element.crossOrigin = 'anonymus';
        element.play();      
      }, 0);
    },
  }
```

Working example on https://jsfiddle.net/AndersBillLinden/6x8hzrga/